# Why are both expressions in this clojure if evaluated?

Tags: clojure, quil

If I create a new project with

```
lein new quil foo
```

then reduce the src/foo/core.clj to

```
(ns foo.core
  (:require [quil.core :as q]
            [quil.middleware :as m]))

(defn draw [state]
  (if (< (rand) 0.5)
    (q/line 0 0 500 500)
    (q/line 0 500 500 0)))

(q/defsketch foo
  :title "Try this at home"
  :size [500 500]
  :draw draw
  :features [:keep-on-top]
  :middleware [m/fun-mode])
```

and evaluate the program in `lein repl` with `(use 'foo.core)`, both lines are drawn (i.e. I get a big X). `(if (< (rand) 0.5) true false)` works as expected, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably `draw` is called many times - it wouldn't be a very interactive framework if it only drew the screen once! Some of those times, you randomly choose to draw one line, and sometimes the other; and you never erase either. As a result, both of them are visible on the screen.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I foolishly expected it not to in the absence of an update function, but from an implementation perspective, this makes more sense.